# Producer consumer pattern : on demand thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following class:

```
public class TaskWorkDemo {
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private final ArrayDeque<String> mQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    private Thread mThread;

    private String getOne(){
        synchronized (mLock){
            return mQueue.isEmpty() ? null : mQueue.peek();
        }
    }

    //--produce--
    private void putOne(String s){
        synchronized (mLock){
            mQueue.offer(s);
        }

        //-- at time T --
        if(mThread == null || !mThread.isAlive()){
            mThread = new Thread(new Runner());
            mThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class Runner implements Runnable{

        //--consume--
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String s = getOne();

            while (s != null){
                System.out.println(s);
                s = getOne();
            }

            //-- at time T --
            mThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer thread should exist only if there are pending strings in the queue, i.e. no waiting on the queue like the typical usage we see. So, I'm trying to create a thread every time something is added to queue, by checking if any previous thread does not exists, or has finished.

But this approach has a corner case (see `//-- at time T --` in code above): consumer thread is out of the loop, but not finished yet. producer thread is about to check if previous consumer thread is still around or not, it will find that it is still *finishing*, and skip to create a new one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set `mThread` to null, as it's eventually going to result in a `NullPointerException`:

1. thread1 checks `mThread == null`, which returns false
2. thread2 sets `mThread = null`
3. thread1 checks `!mThread.isAlive()`, which throws a `NullPointerException`

You should probably use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to solve your problem as kan suggests in his answer, but if for some reason you can't / won't do this then you can replace your

```
if(mThread == null || !mThread.isAlive())
```

condition with a

```
while(mThread.isAlive()) {
    sleep(sleep_parameter);
}
// mThread is no longer alive
mThread = new Thread(new Runner());
mThread.start();
```

loop, which will loop until the thread terminates.  A more efficient alternative than sleeping is to use something like a `Semaphore` so that the consumer can signal when its thread is about to terminate (the producer passes a `Semaphore` with zero permits to the consumer and then calls `acquire` on the semaphore which causes it to block; the consumer then calls `release` on the semaphore when it's about to terminate, which wakes up the producer)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think that if while loop is able to raise a flag every time, that another round is due, the thread creating logic should skip creating a new thread. There will be brief moment when there are two threads, but only for a very short time.

Comment: It also should be a lock (or at least volatile keyword) around mThread restart, otherwise if `putOne` invoked concurrently form several threads, it may start several consumer threads. Also the while-sleep will lock producer threads, which maybe also undesired.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JDK ThreadPoolExecutor. It allows you specify minimum thread count (zero in your case), maximum thread size (one in your case) and keep alive timeout (a time which a thread will be hanging around while queue is empty).

Answer (score 0):

If `putOne` is sparsely called, then the race condition won't occur. If it is frequently called, then you shouldn't nullify the thread.

(this answer assumes this is a kind of an exercise, as it is clearly not the way to implement producer-consumer algorithms in a multi-threaded environment)